# Boost's boostrap cannot find windows.h on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, windows, boost, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to compile boost because when I use a prebuilt version of boost cmake does not find the libraries.

I open the Visual Studio command prompt as administrator, run the bootstrap file and I get an error which is not very specific. However the boostrap.log file shows this error.

```
###
### Using 'vc12' toolset.
###

C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine>if exist bootstrap rd /S /Q bootstrap 

C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine>md bootstrap 

C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine>cl /nologo /RTC1 /Zi /MTd /Fobootstrap/ /Fdbootstrap/ -DNT -DYYDEBUG -wd4996 kernel32.lib advapi32.lib user32.lib /Febootstrap\jam0  command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c execcmd.c execnt.c filent.c frames.c function.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c pathnt.c pathsys.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c md5.c class.c cwd.c w32_getreg.c native.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c 
command.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
compile.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
constants.c
debug.c
execcmd.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
execnt.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
filent.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
frames.c
function.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
glob.c
hash.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
hdrmacro.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
headers.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
jam.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
jambase.c
jamgram.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
lists.c
make.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
make1.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
object.c
Generating Code...
Compiling...
option.c
output.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
parse.c
pathnt.c
pathnt.c(24) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
pathsys.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
regexp.c
rules.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
scan.c
search.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
subst.c
timestamp.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
variable.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
modules.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
strings.c
filesys.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
builtins.c
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\timestamp.h(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
md5.c
class.c
cwd.c
w32_getreg.c
w32_getreg.c(18) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
Generating Code...
Compiling...
native.c
set.c
path.c
regex.c
property-set.c
sequence.c
order.c
Generating Code...
```

Comment: Have you installed the windows sdk?

Comment: @Rook I installed Visual Studio 2013 shouldn't that include the SDKs etc

Comment: Not necessarily. I use VS2013 Express; it didn't come with the windows sdk. A quick search will find the appropriate download links.

Comment: @Rook Well my SDK folder is quite full... Has 7.1(A) and 8.1(A) folders

Comment: ...and have you checked that an appropriate set of headers and libs is in there? and that thet directories they live in are included in your project's C++ directories configuration? Installing the sdk ensures those things.